# Second order differential equation with function of Jacobi elliptic function as a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-functions

Many years ago, I remember reading in a book how to transform the following ODE
$$
f'' = af^3 -bf + c/f^3
$$
into a form that lead to a solution in terms of Jacobi elliptic functions. If I am not mistaken, the final solution was of the form
$$
f = \sqrt{\alpha + \beta\, {\rm sn}^2}
$$
where sn is the Jacobi elliptic sine function.  (This might have been in a limit where sn becomes $\tanh$.) However, I do not see how to prove this.

Comment: Multiplying through by $f’$ sets the stage for one integration.